# Como fazer uma requisição HTTP GET para um web service com o Arduino

Tags: c, c++, web-service, arduino

Com fazer uma requisição via GET para um web service com o **Arduino**, usando a seguinte URL e passando um parâmetro http://192.168.0.1:8080/automacao/Sensor?valor=###, onde ### é variável e é atualizado de 30 em 30 segundos, com auxilio de uma placa **Shield**.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// this must be unique
byte mac[] = {  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

// change to your network settings
IPAddress ip(192,168,2,2);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 2, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

// change to your server
IPAddress server(74,125,227,16); // Google

//Change to your domain name for virtual servers
char serverName[] = "www.meuservidor.com.br";
// If no domain name, use the ip address above
// char serverName[] = "74.125.227.16";

// change to your server's port
int serverPort = 80;

EthernetClient client;
int totalCount = 0;
char pageAdd[64];

// set this to the number of milliseconds delay
// this is 30 seconds
#define delayMillis 30000UL

unsigned long thisMillis = 0;
unsigned long lastMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // disable SD SPI
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

  // Start ethernet
  Serial.println(F("Starting ethernet..."));
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, gateway, subnet);

  // If using dhcp, comment out the line above 
  // and uncomment the next 2 lines plus the Ethernet.maintain call in loop

  // if(!Ethernet.begin(mac)) Serial.println(F("failed"));
  // else Serial.println(F("ok"));

  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  delay(2000);
  Serial.println(F("Ready"));
}

void loop()
{
  // If using dhcp to get an IP, uncomment the next line
  // Ethernet.maintain();

  thisMillis = millis();

  if(thisMillis - lastMillis > delayMillis)
  {
    lastMillis = thisMillis;

    // Modify next line to load different page
    // or pass values to server
    sprintf(pageAdd,"/",totalCount);

    // sprintf(pageAdd,"/arduino.php?test=%u",totalCount);

    if(!getPage(server,serverPort,pageAdd)) Serial.print(F("Fail "));
    else Serial.print(F("Pass "));
    totalCount++;
    Serial.println(totalCount,DEC);
  }    
}

byte getPage(IPAddress ipBuf,int thisPort, char *page)
{
  int inChar;
  char outBuf[128];

  Serial.print(F("connecting..."));

  if(client.connect(ipBuf,thisPort) == 1)
  {
    Serial.println(F("connected"));

    sprintf(outBuf,"GET %s HTTP/1.1",page);
    client.println(outBuf);
    sprintf(outBuf,"Host: %s",serverName);
    client.println(outBuf);
    client.println(F("Connection: close\r\n"));
  } 
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("failed"));
    return 0;
  }

  // connectLoop controls the hardware fail timeout
  int connectLoop = 0;

  while(client.connected())
  {
    while(client.available())
    {
      inChar = client.read();
      Serial.write(inChar);
      // set connectLoop to zero if a packet arrives
      connectLoop = 0;
    }

    connectLoop++;

    // if more than 10000 milliseconds since the last packet
    if(connectLoop > 10000)
    {
      // then close the connection from this end.
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(F("Timeout"));
      client.stop();
    }
    // this is a delay for the connectLoop timing
    delay(1);
  }

  Serial.println();

  Serial.println(F("disconnecting."));
  // close client end
  client.stop();

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: c++? Tem certeza?

Comment: Você já fez a conexão do Arduino com a rede via Ethernet?

Comment: Sim já realizei a conexão usando a placa Shield Ethernet.

Comment: Poste o código que vc já fez. É importante saber qual biblioteca Ethernet você está utilizando, entre outras coisas. Para ser mais completo: Quando eu perguntei se você já conectou via Ethernet é, além da placa e rede fisicamente, se você já tem código que se comunica... ou seja, seu Arduino já tem um MAC/IP na rede?

Comment: Postei o código,  minha duvida é em relação ao envio de parâmetros para o web service através de requisições HTTP GET ou POST, até consegui fazer a requisição mais o parâmetro não é enviado.

Comment: @BrunoRichart, seu código já está bem avançado. Qual o problema que você está enfrentando?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo enviar os parâmetros com o valor dos sensores para o web service.

Comment: Boa tarde, não duplique perguntas sem necessidade. Recomendo que leia o Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help - (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101531/3635)

Comment: @BrunoRichart, quais componentes você usou para fazer o HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente reproduzir o exemplo descrito aqui: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

Entretanto, substitua o seguinte trecho de código para a sua realidade:

```
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    //Faz uma requisição HTTP
    client.println("GET /automacao/Sensor?valor=10 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.0.1");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    //Caso não seja possível obter uma conexao
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
```

Note que está sendo montada uma requisição HTTP para o servidor especificado na variável **server** e no cabeçalho HTTP (GET), a URL para qual a requisição deve ser feita. O valor do sensor está fixo como 10 (lembre-se, é só um exemplo).

Creio que esse exemplo é bem simples e com ele você saberá se tudo funciona para a chamada Web Service, em outras palavras, é um código mais simples com o objetivo de isolar outras partes.

Comment: Perfeito @cantoni, funcionou muito obrigado.