# Interpretar a resposta JSON de um WebService que foi chamado pelo Arduino

Tags: c, json, web-service, arduino

Com faço para interpretar informações de um **WebService** que foi chamado pelo Arduino?

O WebService retorna um JSON e preciso interpretá-lo. Um exemplo da resposta pode ser vista abaixo:

```
[{"valor":"10"}]
```

O código abaixo, obtido desse [site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient), mostra a chamada e a interpretação, porém é lido um byte por vez e, por isso, tenho dúvidas de como poderia fazer isso para o retorno em JSON.

A parte que lê um byte por vez pode ser vista abaixo:

```
if (client.available()) {
  char c = client.read();
  Serial.print(c);
}
```

**Código completo:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101273/como-fazer-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-get-para-um-web-service-com-o-arduino

Comment: Eu não entendi bem o que o arduino tem haver com o webservice, se na verdade quem conecta no webservice é `c` e parece que não tem relação alguma com a parte "Serial". Poderia explicar, talvez ajude a entender a sua duvida.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, no contexto dessa pergunta, quem conecta no Webservice é o Arduino. No código acima, as instruções que usam a Serial estão servindo como um espécie de logger para saber o que está acontecendo no programa. Enfim, ele se conecta no Webservice utilizando Ethernet e usa a saída Serial do Arduino para acompanhar essa conexão.

Comment: Creio que essa pergunta tenha sido fechada equivocadamente. Não sei se antes ou depois da edição do autor. A pergunta não é tão diferente dessa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101273/como-fazer-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-get-para-um-web-service-com-o-arduino

Comment: @cantoni entenda que fechar não é quase nunca equivocado, se a pergunta foi fechada é porque o autor não deixou claro, no momento que o autor melhorar a pergunta ela pode ser reaberta, note que isto já foi discutido várias vezes, recomendo que leia esta discussão do meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 O autor não deixou claro em vários sentidos, se você entendeu a duvida você pode editar a pergunta e melhorar ela, assim ela entra automaticamente no processo de votação para reabrir, serão 5 votos necessários para reabrir - espero que entenda ;)

Comment: @cantoni na verdade é esta pergunta é duplicata da outra, só que lá parece mais claro. Se eu soubesse da outra teria votado como duplicata

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não sabia da parte que após uma edição a pergunta entra automaticamente pra fila de reabrir. Bom saber. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa. Note que essa pergunta aqui deseja interpretar a resposta JSON de uma chamada WebService. A outra pergunta citada por mim deseja apenas fazer a chamada.

Comment: Ok, mas aqui a pergunta esta *bem confusa* e como eu disse se você sabe como melhorar, então melhore, este é o principal fundamento do StackOverflow http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/3635 - Mas edite sem descaracterizar e só apenas se tiver certeza @cantoni.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, pergunta editada. Obrigado.

Comment: @cantoni Por nada, só recomendo que incentive sempre primeiro o autor editar por ele mesmo, pois as vezes (em outras futuras perguntas) pode ser que o autor queira outra coisa. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diferente do que acontece em linguagens de alto nivel como Python e PHP, no C (principalmente no Arduino) ao fazer uma requisição, será devolvido caractere por caractere do web service e não existem funções prontas para de auxiliar.

No caso, se você imprimir isso na sua serial, vai parecer que tudo chegou de uma unica vez, mas não se engane. Para receber dados de um web service você precisa ler os dados recebidos, byte por byte, guardar em um buffer. Primeiro você deve filtrar os cabeçalhos, já que normalmente não são úteis, ao receber dois `/r/n` você saberá que o cabeçalho HTTP acabou, dai guarde no buffer o corpo de sua resposta.

Quando o cliente terminar a requisição, realize um parser no buffer buscando suas informações. Realmente é tudo na mão, não tem funções prontas para esse tipo de situação e todas as bibliotecas que já usei para [parsear JSON em C](https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson) são pesadas e gastam quase toda memória do Arduino.

Exemplo de como pego o valor de resposta e salvo em um buffer

```
[... monte de código acima...]
while (http.connected()) {
            while (http.available()) {

                char read_char = http.read();
                Serial.print(read_char); /* Imprime resposta do servidor */

                if (read_char != '\n' && newLine != 1) {
                  resposta[i] = read_char;
                  i++;
                  resposta[i] = '\0';
                }

                if (read_char == '\n') {
                  newLine = 1;
                }
            }

            i = 0;
        }
[... monte de código abaixo....]
```

Depois disso tenho na variável resposta o que o servidor me retornou, ai uso o `strtok` para quebrar a resposta em pedaços

No seu exemplo, você tem a instrução `char c = client.read();` é ai que você vai ter a resposta do servidor, o problema é que ela só possui um caractere, então você vai ter que ir jogando ela em uma matriz para conseguir ler toda a resposta. Depois, em outro ponto, quando for interpretar o que chegou do servidor, lê essa matriz de caracteres (string) e busca pelo que você quer

Comment: Poste um código com um pequeno exempo. Não precisa ser tudo, somente a parte relevante, ou seja, a parte de montar a requisição e a parte de interpretar a resposta. Será de grande ajuda.

Comment: Eu não tenho um código pronto mais tenho um exemplo do site do arduino parecido mais esse não le os parâmetros retornados que podem ser json o do tipo text mesmo.

Comment: então, para ler os parâmetros você precisa criar um lógica que pegue esses dados. eu sempre uso caracteres de controle, leio tudo entre pipes ou cerquilha, dou um split nesses dados e como conheço a ordem dos elementos, atribuo a variáveis .

Comment: Entendo @CarlosCandido, o comentário foi para o Renato postar um código. De qualquer maneira, como ele disse, você vai precisar escrever um pouco de código para interpretar esse JSON. A não ser que tenha alguma biblioteca do Arduino que te ajude nisso.

Comment: Não precisa ser somente json, pode ser text mesmo, apenas preciso pegar valores retornados do Web Service com o Arduino.

Comment: Mas esse link tem um exemplo: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient Veja esse trecho do codigo no loop: char c = client.read(); aí é feita a leitura de 1 byte.